# How to link against GLESv2 in Visual Studio 2015 preview?

Tags: android, android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

It seems the GLESv1_cm is linked to by default within the Android project, so I've attempted adding 'GLESv2' (and I've also tried adding 'GLESv2_cm') to the library dependencies. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have any effect. Functions like `glCompileShader` still do not compile.

How do I link against GLESv2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, I am an idiot... Be sure to update pch.h

```
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
```